# Can't connect to ASP.NET core through docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Hi people have been looking at this for far too long and need some help.

I have made a ASP.NET core website nothing fancy just the template that goes with VS 2017 (v 1.1). I publish the site using dotnet core cli and build an image using this dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime
COPY /Publish /dotnetapp
WORKDIR /dotnetapp

EXPOSE 8444
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Inqu.dll"]
```

When i run the image created with:

```
docker run -it <image_name:tag> -p 8444:8444
```

The image starts up waiting for request:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /dotnetapp
Now listening on: http://*:8444
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

but i can't reach the site and getting an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to access the site thought http://local-ip:8444/

I have modified the WebHostBuild to:

```
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://*:8444")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

So it should listen to port 8444, I have also tried to set:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:8444
```

in the Dockerfile but it doesnt help.

---

I have some other images in docker up and running (gogs and mysql) and i can access them with my local ip:port with no problems, but i can't connect to the kestrel server.

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was a stupid mistake arguments were in wrong order

```
docker run -it -p 8444:8444 <image_name:tag>
```

and it worked :\

Comment: Trying to figure it out for two hours, thank you for saving me next two!

Comment: I learnt this the hard way too.  According to [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) anything entered after the image name is related to [cmd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).