# Localhost connection refused while trying to connect to aspnet core app on docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Toolbox because I have win 10 Home Edition.

There is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.2"

networks:
   frontend:
   backend:

services:
   catalog:
      build:
         context: .\src\Services\ProductCatalogApi
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: microservices-v1.0.0
      environment:
         - DatabaseServer=mssqlserver
         - DatabaseName=CatalogDb
         - DatabaseUser=sa
         - DatabaseUserPassword=ProductApi(!)
      container_name: catalogapi
      ports:
         - "5000:80"
      networks:
         - backend
         - frontend
      depends_on:
         - mssqlserver

   mssqlserver:
      image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest"
      ports:
         - "2200:1433"
      container_name: mssqlcontainer
      environment:
         - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
         - SA_PASSWORD=ProductApi(!)
      networks:
         - backend
```

I have a mssqlserver instance as well which works fine and I can connect to it via address ip without problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0 AS build

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish --output /out/ --configuration Release

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.0

COPY --from=build /out /app/

WORKDIR  /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","ProductCatalogApi.dll"]
```

What I have tried so far?

1. [Can't connect to ASP.NET core through docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824716/cant-connect-to-asp-net-core-through-docker)
   Define .UseUrls in Program.cs file
2. [Unable to access Docker application from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666490/unable-to-access-docker-application-from-browser)
3. Connect via: localhost:5000/swagger, addrress_ip/swagger (I obtain address sing docker inspect), address_ip:5000/swagger

My source code:
https://github.com/AGranosik/microservices-udemy-v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only think you need to do while using docker on Win 10 Home is check via cmd address of you VM machine (default).
Commmand:

```
docker-machine ls
```

Then you get a machine's ip which you put before port instead of localhost.